# Linear Optimization in R using lpSolve Package

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

I am learning about linear optimization in R using the lpSolve package. I am wondering if the lp() function in R can sometimes find a solution that is a saddle point and not the true min/max. I have looked at the documentation of the package and I haven't found anything about saddle points or how the optimization function works. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. LP solvers find the global optimum. Saddle points or local optima are not an issue.